# Syntax to return date in Append Into Statement

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba

Using the following code in an Access 2010 database on a search form returns the search results by date but the report is empty when previewed.  The search form returns the search results by Invoice Number and the report is perfect when previewed. I think the error is in the Append To line having to do with the date format and have been unable to figure out the correct syntax to append the date search results to my temp table.  Suggestions or solutions would be appreciated.

```
 'Search for a specific date on date field
If IsDate(Me.TxtSearch) Then 'DATE SEARCH WORKS
SearchDate = Format(Me.TxtSearch.Value, Shortdate)
Task = "SELECT * FROM [Invoices] WHERE ((InvoiceDate Like ""*" & SearchDate & "*""))"
Me.RecordSource = Task
Me.TxtSearch.BackColor = vbWhite
Else
strsearch = Trim(Me.TxtSearch)
strsearch = Me.TxtSearch.Value
Task = "Select * FROM [Invoices] WHERE ((InvoiceNo Like ""*" & strsearch & "*"") OR (InvoiceDate Like ""*" & SearchDate & "*""))"
Me.RecordSource = Task
Me.TxtSearch.BackColor = vbWhite
'Append data matching keyword from the search result into the Temp Invoices table
strAppend = "INSERT INTO [Invoices_Temp] SELECT * FROM [Invoices] WHERE ((InvoiceNo Like ""*" & strsearch & "*"") OR (InvoiceDate Like #" & SearchDate & "#))"
'strAppend = "INSERT INTO [Invoices_Temp] SELECT * FROM [Invoices] WHERE ((InvoiceNo Like ""*" & strsearch & "*"") AND (InvoiceDate Like ""*" & SearchDate & "" * "))"
DoCmd.RunSQL strAppend
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a proper format for the string expression for the date, and *Like* doesn't work for dates:

```
SearchDate = Format(Me!TxtSearch.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")
Task = "SELECT * FROM [Invoices] WHERE (InvoiceDate = #" & SearchDate & "#)"
```

Comment: Gustav appreciate the quick response but that did not work. The search runs fine with the code currently used, what is not working is the preview report portion where the records are appended to Invoice_Temp table. Something is wrong here 
strAppend = "INSERT INTO [Invoices_Temp] SELECT * FROM [Invoices] WHERE ((InvoiceNo Like ""*" & strsearch & "*"") OR (InvoiceDate Like #" & SearchDate & "#))"
'strAppend = "INSERT INTO [Invoices_Temp] SELECT * FROM [Invoices] WHERE ((InvoiceNo Like ""*" & strsearch & "*"") AND (InvoiceDate Like ""*" & SearchDate & "" * "))"

Comment: I wonder why you would expect that to work, so far the syntax is from the syntax of the code in my answer.